# Unable to install homebrew on mac

Tags: git, macos, curl, homebrew

I wanted to install homebrew on my mac but wasn't able to

i tried running the homebrew cmd on my terminal but i keep getting an error
something like this

curl: (35) error:140943E8:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:reason(1000)

[image: 1]

Comment: It looks like GitHub technical issues. Try it again later

Comment: Seems like a popular error recently: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74985167/7976758